# is "newBlockHeaders" in web3 emits a legit block?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, synchronization, blocks, confirmations

I'm using [web3.eth.subscribe('newBlockHeaders')](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.7/web3-eth-subscribe.html#subscribe-newblockheaders) to track transaction I sent to the blockchain. My question is that is the block emitted from "newBlockHeaders" legit or in other words, the block has enough confirmations to be the block that will stay forever?